# Save password on android 16+ API

Tags: android

How can i store password in android app securely with 16+ API?

I know how to do it with 18+, but can't find any examples for 16+

Comment: Saving the password in a file, database, or `SharedPreferences` has been possible since API Level 1. If you save to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which is the default for most of those options, only those who root the device will be able to get at the password. If you feel that this is insufficient -- and in some cases, it is -- what are you using on API Level 18 that you feel that is sufficient? Perhaps we can suggest something that works like what you want to use... but to do that, we need to know what you want to use.

Comment: on 18+ api becomes available cryptography encryption i believe

Comment: Various cryptography options, such as `javax.crypto`, have been around since API Level 1. Again, please explain **exactly** what you think is available on API Level 18, but not API Level 16, that you want to use.

Comment: I just can't find examples, that will work on 16-17, e.g.
KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder needs 18
thanks, for javax.crypto, will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hash the password using SHA1, and store the hash using `SharedPreferences`

Then, when you want to check for a valid password, hash it again, and compare against the hash you saved previously.

This is good for when you don't want to retrieve the password, but merely check if it's valid

If you want to also retrieve the password, you will need to use some different encryption method, since SHA1 is one-way

I've found [this](https://github.com/brainattica/android-rsa-sample) example on how to implement the RSA protocol in Android, which is a 2-way asymmetric encryption scheme, and will work well when you want to also retrieve the password for further use:

Comment: I upwote this, because its really useful in some cases, but i want to retrieve password and send it to server